# How to run python script that needed exe file in windows

Tags: python, windows, doxygen

i tried to build a doc for https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp

The command for that is

```
python doxybuild.py --doxygen=$(which doxygen) --open --with-dot
```

Here i keep getting error in

```
$(which doxygen)
```

which is linux command i think, since i use windows. After see the help in

```
python doxybuild.py --help
```

I know that it's asking for doxy path. So i run the script with

```
python doxybuild.py --doxygen=C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin --open --with-dot
```

But i still get execption saying that

```
C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin is not a file
```

I tried

```
C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin\doxygen.exe
```

Still the same error. Anyone can help me with building this doxygen doc on windows or running python script that need exe file in windows? Thanks.

My pc run on windows 10.

[EDIT]
Python script where i keep getting exception

```
def assert_is_exe(path):
    if not path:
        raise Exception('path is empty.')
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception('%r is not a file.' %path)
    if not os.access(path, os.X_OK):
        raise Exception('%r is not executable by this user.' %path)
```

Comment: try adding quotes. "C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin\doxygen.exe"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I should put it as an answer instead of a comment:

Try adding quotes. "C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin\doxygen.exe"